# Calculating kerf spacing for elliptical perimeter

Tags: geometry

How would one calculate the kerf spacing of cuts to be made to a board, using a defined kerf width & cut depth to bend the board into a specific elliptical shape.
Work has already been done to calculate the cut spacing for a single-radius curve, applying those variables.  See that calculator here: https://www.blocklayer.com/kerf-spacingeng

**Is there an equation the would allow one to input the data calculated from the above website (kerf spacing for single radius curve for given kerf width and cut depth) in order to calculate the spacing for the ellipse, using the length and width (from center) of the ellipse?**
Any other successful solutions are also welcome, whether or not they use the above single-radius kerf spacing calculator!

Thank you!

Supporting info: “Kerf” refers to the width of a saw blade, so it pertains to the amount of material removed from a saw cut.  By removing material from one side of a straight piece of material (such as a thin board) with properly-spaced cuts, one can bend that straight piece to a specific radius.  If this is done precisely with a thin saw blade, the saw kerf slots can even be glued back together without leaving significant gaps, creating a nearly seamless curve.
**The goal is to create predictable results for this process while producing complex curves, mostly composed of elliptical edges.**